# VBA Intersect Target Errors on Multiple Cell Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue where I use this statement (below) to replace any cell within a specified range to auto default to "$0" if the cell has been emptied or deleted. The problem is that if I select multiple cells and delete or use the click and drag calculate feature to autofill dollar amounts then I throw a "type mismatch" error on the elseif line.

Can someone help me find a workaround to still mass delete or fill a group of cells?

Statement below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("Editable")) Is Nothing Then
    ElseIf Target = "" Then Target = "$0"
    End If
    Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to iterate `Target` and test each one individually.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the comment. I'll give it a shot to iterate to the fixed areas.

Comment: @scottcraner I'm having a rough time getting a loop pieced together. Any chance you can whip one up easily? My initial target range would be F9 to Q12. Any cells in this area if changed singularly or in a multiple would need looked at.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Replace Blank Cells

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(Target, Range("Editable"))
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim urg As Range
    Dim iCell As Range

    For Each iCell In irg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(iCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then
                Set urg = iCell
            Else
                Set urg = Union(urg, iCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next iCell

    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        urg.Value = "$0"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Calculate ' ?

End Sub
```